# Why require('require') throws error in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am beginner for Node js. I am going through the node js documentation, it says require and module are the two core modules of node js for managing dependencies.
Both of them have a global scope so we don't need to require('require').

We know require('somefile') function is used to include a module.
Just for the curiosity, I tried to include in-build require module of node js in my js file.
This is the code in my js file named app.js

```
require('require');
require('module');
console.log('starting app');
```

I got an error:

[image]

Can someone explain me the reason of this error. As per the definition if require function in node js, this code is logically correct. I know require and module are by default available because of their global scope. But why node throws error when we try to explicitly include **require** module.

Comment: You don't need to require require module. Just remove `require('require')`

Comment: The error means that no module named "require" can be found; it's not anywhere in your module path. Note that the error comes at the top of a method called `"resolveFilename"`.

Comment: yes - there is no need to import `require` - anyway, in your example you are trying to reference to `require` before the `require` module would have been loaded. But just like @Héctor said this is not necessary

Comment: That I know, but my question is why require('require') throws error. We know require itself is a module, so trying to import require module using require function shouldn't throw error. Just want to know the reason behind this error.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/4450187/messerbill, Node js doesn't throws error if we try to load the same module twice. this works 
const fs = require('fs');
require('fs');

Comment: it is not about loading twice but about referencing to a name which was not yet imported. But have a look inside your `node_modules` folder

Answer (score 1):

Just as the error describes, a module under the name "require" cannot be found.

Node.js does include a "core modules" list within itself on which it will try to look for modules at first hand. And 'require' is certainly not a module defined there. It will then try to search on other directories, such as "node_modules" and then even the current directory where your file is resting at. There is **no** module called "require" within Node.js' core modules list nor on your node_modules folder nor on your current directory (If you actually do have a module called "require" within any of these directories, then the error might be related to something else. Add that piece of information to your question if that's the case). Therefore Node is giving you the error you see when trying to fetch for a module called "require". The node.js algorithm to search for modules is explained with more detail [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2169-where-does-node-js-and-require-look-for-modules.htm)

Now, you may be asking yourself "**where does the require method come from then?**". The "*require*" function is actually defined within the module.js module of Node, which is one of the core modules included in Node. So it works right out of the box, as many other functions that come in prepared within the Node environment. You can find a reference and more in-depth info about how it works [here](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/)

Comment: Now, you may be asking yourself "where does the require method come from then?". The "require" function is actually defined within the module.js module of Node... I think require method comes from require module. just type require on node repl, you will see { [Function: require]
  resolve: { [Function: resolve] paths: [Function: paths] },
  main: undefined,
  extensions: { '.js': [Function], '.json': [Function], '.node': [Function] },
  cache: {} }

Comment: @ReenaUpadhyay What are you actually calling "require module"? Yes, if you console log the require function, you will get something similar to what you just copy-pasted there. So what? I still don't get your point. Try to get to the bare-bone of your question: what's the code behind "require()"? Right? You can check it for yourself at nodejs repo on GitHub. [This](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/blob/master/lib/module.js) is a link to the actual file which defines require. Search for "Module.prototype.require" on that file.